# Drop down menu in codeigniter displays nothing

Tags: php, codeigniter, drop-down-menu, dynamically-generated

I'm having some trouble displaying the values retrieved from a db and displaying them in a dropdown menu, using codeigniter. The code is as follows:

**Controller:**

```
<?php
class AuthorSignupC extends CI_Controller
{
    function index()
    {
        $this->load->model('AuthorSignupM');
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $data['title']= 'All Conferences';
        $data['groups'] = $this->AuthorSignupM->ViewAllConf();
        $this->load->view('AuthorSignup', $data);
     }
}
```

**Model:**

```
<?php
class AuthorSignupM extends CI_Model
{
    function ViewAllConf()
    {
      $this->db->select('ConfLName');
      $this->db->from('conference');
      //$query = $this->db->query('SELECT ConfLName FROM conference');
      $query = $this->db->get();
      return $query->result();      
    }
}
?>
```

**View:**

```
<select class="form-control">
            <?php 
            foreach($groups as $row)
            { 
              echo '<option value="'.$row->description.'">'.$row->description.'</option>';
            }
            ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're selecting just one column:

```
$this->db->select('ConfLName');
$this->db->from('conference');
```

but retrieving 'description', and I guess your error reporting is set too low to show you the error.

You should loop over `confLName` (or use `$this->db->select('description');`)

```
<select class="form-control">
    <?php foreach($groups as $row) : ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $row->ConfLName;?>"><?php echo $row->ConfLName;?></option>
    <?php endforeach;?>
</select>
```

Comment: Oh no. It was a careless mistake. I changed the 'description' to 'ConfLName' and it did the trick. Thanks! :)